# Manage Docker container files from IDE

Tags: apache-http-server, php, docker, ide

I have a docker container php5.6-apache that's hosting my website on my local server.

I was just wondering if there is an IDE that can manage files stored in a docker container. If there is one, please provide the download link.

I don't really know that much about containers, so if i'm asking a stupid question please take it easy.
**PS:** i don't want to install anything on the server.

Comment: You can use IDE of your choice, if you add volumes to your `Dockerfile`. Alternatively  login to the docker shell to manage your files.

Comment: thank you very much.
That's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: You're welcome! I added an answer to make it more clear how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Docker Volumes to mount for example a folder to the container. Then you can manage your files like they were in your local filesystem.

Volume example (from https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

> $ docker run -d \
>     --name devtest \
>     -v myvol2:/app \
>     nginx:latest

Change the parameters suitable for your container.

---

Alternatively you can execute an interactive shell to your container. This way you can manage your files just like in your local shell.

Example (from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

> $ docker exec -it ubuntu_bash bash

Change container id and shell arguments to suit your needs.

**Note** that not every container have `bash`.